# Postgres select & delete where command did not returns empty while the row exists

Tags: postgresql, pg

I'm currently writing an app that has a need to remove a row from a table

I have a junction table where a row has 2 foreign keys, to test them, i tried to hardcode a row (the test one) then tried to post them using pg. hence theres 2 rows.

I tried to delete using pg with the line

```
DELETE FROM playlistsongs WHERE playlist_id = $1 AND song_id = $2 RETURNING id
```

pg returns not found. So out of curiousity, I tried to select the row from the command line. and It returns this

[image: Image attached]

Are there any explanation why the query did not found any data? And how would I delete the row?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably some whitespace. Try `where trim(id) = 'test'`

Comment: thanks for your reply, funnily enough, I reconnected to the db and then its empty. reran the ```select * from playlistsongs where id = 'test'``` worked. run my app and the same behavior occurred. this has to be some logic issue in my app AND whitespace issue in my testing.

Comment: Sounds like a missing `commit`